# Can i develop WPF apps with the Visual Studio 2013 CE targeting OSX/Linux?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, clr

I'm wondering if i can create cross-platform WPF applications using the new Visual Studio 2013 CE. It seems that basically (at least at first) is for ASP.NET development and other web stuffs.
My question is that if the .NET Framework 4.6 includes WPF, does that imply somehow that WPF will be supported on OSX/Linux ??
Some clarification on this or further reading will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

No. WPF is based on DirectX which is only available on Windows.